# How to setup the Shopware development template without docker? (to provide a Shopware platform pull request)

Tags: installation, shopware6

I understand, that in order to contribute to the Shopware platform / core, I have to setup Shopware 6 using the [development](https://%20https://github.com/shopware/development) template.

I followed the steps at
https://github.com/shopware/platform#quickstart--installation

But only until

> ./psh.phar docker:start

I was thinking about installing via `bin/console system:setup` and `bin/console system:install` but it fails with

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException:
 Unable to read the "/home/projects/shopware-dev-bd/bin/../.env" environment file. in 
/home/projects/shopware-dev-bd/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:567
```

Is there an easy way to create the `.env`? Do I have to copy it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended now to use the platform repository directly for setting up development installations.

- Just clone directly from `shopware/platform`
- `composer install`
- `bin/console system:setup` to create the `.env` file
- `composer run setup`
- optionally `bin/console framework:demodata` if you need demo data

Comment: We should update https://github.com/shopware/platform#shopware-6-repository-structure and https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/installation/overview!

Comment: how is the admin theme built in that setup?

Comment: Found it, it's composer scripts

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the accepted answer:

While in the `development` template there was `psr.phar` to manage things like building the admin theme, and in `production` template there is `bin/build-administration.sh` none of those are there in the method described by @dneustadt.

Instead this is managed by **composer scripts** which are defined in the [`composer.json`](https://%20https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/9d58d5a7651965bd365427d54e333830ed26980e/composer.json#L256)

For example admin JS is build using

`composer run build:js:admin`